# How can I effectively diagnose a failing attach_file?

Tags: ruby, rspec, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

Recently,  my sections of capybara that attached files, failed to operate.

```
attach_file('file_upload', 'testfiles/test.doc')
```

Previously, my file paths were not absolute, and that was fine. Then I started receiving a rejection;

```
unknown error: path is not absolute: testfiles/test.doc
```

If I made my path absolute;

```
attach_file('file_upload', '/tmp/test.doc')
```

It would not complain, but fail to attach the file as well.

Has anyone had this issue?  Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: "fail to attach the file as well". Do you have any exception?

Comment: With a full file path, I do not.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue - https://gist.github.com/abotalov/7308732. File is attached normally here. Please provide reproducible example or more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the theory is that some gem version conflict caused the absolute path requirement to kick in.

The file lost visibility on the web app, but was attached, and did upload.

A good fix was to use absolute_path for local to CI migration.

```
attach_file('file_upload', File.absolute_path('testfiles/test.doc'))
```